# get list of values that exists in all the columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data frame  df:

```
value1  value2  value3
1        4      9
2        3      1
3        1      3
5        2      2
6        7      4
```

How do i get the list of values that are common in all the columns. list = [1,2,3] as 1,2,3 are present in all the three columns. I was able to check if the values is in the same row but not the entire data set.

Answer (score 2):

Use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset):

As @RafaelC points out there's no need for `reduce` + `lambda`:

```
set.intersection(*df.agg(set))
{1, 2, 3}
```

---

```
from functools import reduce

list(reduce(lambda x,y: x & y, [*df.agg(set)]))
#[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: No need for `reduce` and `lambda` (messy), just use `set.intersection(*df.agg(set))`

Comment: @RafaelC was not aware of that. You should answer and I can delete, unless there's a decent duplicate.

Comment: Nah, relax. Just add that to your answer ;}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`set(df['value1'])&set(df['value2'])&set(df['value3'])`

Comment: That's virtually the same answer as the others. Now, suppose you have 100 columns. Would you have to write `set(df['Value1'])&.....` all the way too `&set(df['Value100']))?

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
import functools;import operator
functools.reduce(operator.and_,list(map(set,df.values.T)))
Out[278]: {1, 2, 3}
```